# Powershell: Format output of Import-Csv Records in a specific way

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

id like to format the output of CSV Records in a specific way.

Lets say, i have a csv file with these records:

```
Field1,Field2
blah,blah
bluh,bluh
```

Now, what i want to achieve is an output (into console or file) with this format

```
('blah','blah')
('bluh','bluh')
```

This [1] does not work! Powershell simply writes nothing into out.txt.

[1]

```
Import-Csv .\test.csv | Select-Object Field1,Field2 | ForEach-Object {Write-Host "('"$_.Field1"', '"$_.Field2"')"} > .\out.txt
```

Comment: Instead of `Write-Host` you should use `Write-Output` if you intend the text to be output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the format operator:

```
import-csv .\test.csv | %{ "({0},{1})" -f $_.Field1, $_.Field2; }
```

To output to file, simply pipe the output there; i.e.

```
import-csv .\test.csv | %{ "({0},{1})" -f $_.Field1, $_.Field2; } | out-file .\out.txt
```

For more info on the format operator: http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-f-operator.html

Comment: The key here is not the format operator, but that fact that he removes `write-host` so it sends the object(string) to the pipeline(he could also use `Write-Output`, which does the same). `Write-Host` is for interactive messages only, they are not sent as objects that can be piped into another command or written to a file.

Answer (score 2):

Try this if work

```
...{Write-output "('$($_.Field1)', '$($_.Field2)')"} > .\out.txt
```

Dont use write-host